# Order of automorphism group of a $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

This is basically a question regarding a solution from this old topic [Order of automorphism group of a $p$-group is divisible by $p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472539/600843) to the abelian case.
In the only answer of this question, two cases are considered. I can understand the first case, but there is something about the second one which I have a hard time understanding. Why can we say that $G \cong \mathbb{Z_{p^k}} \times H$ where $k\ge 2$?. From the classification theorem of finite abelian groups we just know that $G \cong\mathbb{Z_{p^{\alpha_1}}}\times \mathbb{Z_{p^{\alpha_2}}}\times...\times \mathbb{Z_{p^{\alpha_n}}}$, where $1\le \alpha_1\le \alpha_2 \le...\le \alpha_n$ are integers. I understand the fact that at least one of these integers is greater than $1$ in this case, but to me it looks like we are assuming that $\alpha_1 >1$.

Answer (score 1):

It was not said there that $\alpha_1>1$, but rather, that some of the $\alpha_i$ is greater than 1. The argument in the accepted answer works if any of the direct summands has order $p^k$ with some $k>1$.

Comment: Thanks ! So, can those summands be permuted? The reason why I believed that $\alpha_1 >1$ is because if, let's say, $\alpha_3$ were the one which was $>1$, then we would have something like $G\cong H_1 \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^k} \times H_2$

Comment: @user69503: There is a natural and obvious isomorphism between $G_1\times\cdots\times G_n$ and $G_{\sigma(1)}\times\cdots\times G_{\sigma(n)}$, where $\sigma$ is any permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, even without invoking the universal property of the product.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin You are right, we can just define $f : G_1 \times G_2 \times... \times G_n \to G_{\sigma(1)} \times G_{\sigma(2)}\times... \times G_{\sigma(n)}$, $f(x_1, x_2,..., x_n) =(x_{\sigma(1)}, x_{\sigma(2)},..., x_{\sigma(n)}) $. Even though it is obvious and natural, I had never thought about it.